# How to run a windows command from C

Tags: c, windows

I'm writing a program that returns some physical information of the computer.
I have seen that in Windows there exists the command

```
WMIC CPU GET /FORMAT:LIST
```

That command returns the whole information about the process, I need to use that information from a C program. I mean, I have to run the C program and show that information.

I'm a beginner in C.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa298534%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For viewing purpose you can use this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    system("WMIC CPU GET /FORMAT:LIST");
    return 0;
}
```

And if you want use this information then here the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093714/2317535

Use `popen` instead of `system`. See example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx

```
char   psBuffer[128];
FILE   *pPipe;

if( (pPipe = _popen( "set PATH=%PATH%;C:/Program Files (x86)/myFolder/bin", "rt" )) == NULL )
    exit( 1 );
```

then

```
while(fgets(psBuffer, 128, pPipe)) {
    printf(psBuffer);
}

if (feof( pPipe))
    printf( "\nProcess returned %d\n", _pclose( pPipe ) );
```

Comment: Why do you say to use popen instead of system? (besides you quoting that stackoverflow answer you link to that says those words)

Comment: Because  output of a system call  redirect to stdout. To reuse the output popen can help.

Comment: Yes, [popen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) is the best solution here, because it makes it easy to read the output from wmic.  Don't forget the "pclose()" when you're done (as illustrated above)!

Answer (score 0):

Fair warning: the way presented here is not really an ‘easy’ solution.

[`WMIC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531.aspx) is a command that accesses WMI, [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384642.aspx). `WMIC CPU GET /FORMAT:LIST` presumably gets the CPUs; on the level of WMI itself, you’re probably just trying to get all instances of [`Win32_Processor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373.aspx).

[WMI can be accessed through COM.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389276.aspx) To do so, you’d start by using [`CoCreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615.aspx) to create an [`IWbemLocator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391768.aspx), then calling [`ConnectServer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391769.aspx) to get an [`IWbemServices`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392093.aspx), on which you could run [`ExecQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392107.aspx) to query for `Win32_Processor`s.

Unfortunately, COM is not very easy to access from C, but [it is doable](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C). (Unfortunately I could not find any page on MSDN about it; that CodeProject article is the best I could find.)

I’m not particularly familiar with any of these technologies in great depth, but if you research them all, that’s how you’d connect them together to get that information *natively* rather than by calling out to an external command.